# Magento2 Extensions how to set a module enable activation key

Tags: magento2, license

I have a Extension. How to set a module activation key for customers. if i set a PHP code then someone is commenting that code and run that extension.please provide a best solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use ioncube encoder for encoding the code

Comment: Hello @MurtuzaZabuawala, into all extension files i set a ioncube encoder or only liecense checking file i set a ioncube encoder ?

Comment: only encode those files where your critical business logic were there.

Comment: ohk , i trying it

Comment: But it is paid any free stuff ?

Comment: its paid stuff for encoding you need to pay, and for decoding you have to install its PHP extension ioncube_loader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82175/discussion-between-hardik-makwana-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Answer (score 0):

If you threaten that any one can change your code and activation key will work

then you can encode your module code with `ioncube`.

the only disadvantage of this encoding is that client machine needs `ioncube_loader` in order to run your module